# How to stop tracking in_app_purchase Firebase event on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

Is there are a way to stop tracking `in_app_purchase` Firebase automatically collected event on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible for now. Just got an answer from Firebase support:

> Currently, disabling of in_app_purchase data can only be done on
>   Android, and not on iOS. Disabling of analytics collection on iOS
>   includes every analytics data. However, we've added this to our
>   feature requests list. As of now, we are yet to find out any details
>   or timelines as to when (or if) it will be implemented. You can check
>   our release notes from time to time for any updates about Firebase
>   features and its services.

I created request for adding this feature:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2435

If somebody interested in this feature too, add a comment, please by this link, they will do it faster, will hope.

Comment: Is this still the case? does this make the spend prediction useless on firebase for ios?

Comment: Yes, it's still a case. But it not makes prediction useless, but opened for all firebase users of our team.